# Groovy Property Annotation for Public-Read Protected-Write

Tags: groovy

In groovy, when I want to create a property with public-read but protected-write access, I need to write the following code (as per the [Groovy Docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Beans)):

```
class SomeClass {
    /**
     * Public property
     */
    String someProperty

    /**
     * Make it protected-write
     */
    protected void setSomeProperty(String someProperty) { this.someProperty = someProperty }
}
```

Is there a short-hand for this? Something like:

```
class SomeClass {
    @Protected String someProperty
}
```

There should also be a `@Private` annotation along the same lines.

**Note**

These annotations would only affect the setter method of the property. This should allow any required access-level combination i.e.:

```
/** An entirely protected property */
protected String someProperty

/** An entirely private property */
private String someProperty

/** A read-only property */
final String someProperty

/** Private-Setter, Protected-Getter */
@Private protected String someProperty
```

Comment: `groovy.transform.PackageScope` annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not any shorthand way to express that, at least not in default Groovy.  You could write an AST transformation which imposes rules like those you describe but Groovy does not do anything like that by default.

I hope that helps.